# Problem on PC browser/screen 3 columns (split article) with responsive design (html)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, containers

```
<div class="row articles">
<div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <article>
       <p></p>
   </article>
   <article>
       <p></p>
   </article>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <article>
       <p></p>
   </article>
   <article>
       <p></p>
   </article>
</div>
</div>
```

When I resize on PC it gives me only 2 columns instead of 3
i have made the "meta/viewport" as well as the "clear" things the responsive design is working well on mobile and tablet but when it comes to PC screen it will do strange things no matter what i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulting the [documentation for Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content) I noticed you're missing the `.col` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row articles">
<div class="col col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <article>
       <p>Article 1</p>
   </article>
   <article>
       <p>Article 2</p>
   </article>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <article>
       <p>Article 3</p>
   </article>
   <article>
       <p>Article 4</p>
   </article>
</div>
<div class="col col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <article>
       <p>Article 5</p>
   </article>
   <article>
       <p>Article 6</p>
   </article>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you i didn't noticed. but it don't fix my issue

Comment: Can you explain? What is shown instead for you? Do you see at least columns? (So that we only need to look into the sizing)

Comment: when i take the "iphone" size it give me one column, when resising to tablets it gives me 2 columns but when i'm resizing to laptop size the website have 3 columns but no matter what i try nothing displays in the third

Comment: Well, if you just have two columns in there, a third one won't appear. I added „Article 5 and 6” to show how that would be constructed.

Comment: i just fixed my issue, in fact it was in my css: a "clear" property that i forgot to cancel when resising,sorry for the inconvenience.